# What support does Jaspal Atwal have?

Tags: terrorism, canada

I’ve seen some mentions about Jaspal Atwal on Twitter, and commentary on the failure to not notice he was on the guest list - a failure to oppose him.

But what I don’t get is if you look at it in the other direction: why do some Canadian politicians support him or associate with him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Canadian press, the MP responsible was [Randeep Sarai](https://www.surreynowleader.com/news/surrey-mp-apologizes-for-inviting-criminal-to-trudeau-reception/).

He never officially stated what his ties are, but being a Sikh, it's not entirely impossible if he supports Sikh nationalism (which is Atwal's cause). It seems to be a popular position in Canada's Sikh communities as per the linked article.